# Caterpillar plot of posterior brms samples: Order factors in a ggdist plot (stat_slab)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I ran a bayesian linear mixed model with brms and can plot the estimates nicely but I can't figure out how to order the single-subject estimates based on the mean of the posterior samples (so as to get a caterpillar plot). This is what I've done.

Toy data:

```
library(brms)
library(tidybayes)
library(tidyverse)

n = 20
n_condition = 6
ABC =
  tibble(
    condition = rep(c("A","B","C","D","E","F"), n),
    response = rnorm(n * 6, c(0,1,2,1,-1,-2), 0.5),
    treatment = rnorm(n * 6, c(0,1,2,1,-1,-2), 0.5),
    subject = c(rep("X",(n_condition*n)/3),rep("Y",(n_condition*n)/3),rep("Z",(n_condition*n)/3))
  )
```

Add a shift for some subjects

```
ABC$response[ABC$subject == "X"] = 20 + ABC$response[ABC$subject == "X"]
ABC$response[ABC$subject == "Y"] = -20 + ABC$response[ABC$subject == "Z"]
```

Run the model

```
m = brm(
  response ~ treatment + (1|condition) + (1|subject),
  data = ABC,
  cores = 4, chains = 1,
  iter = 500, warmup = 50
)
```

Plot

```
m %>%
  spread_draws(b_treatment, r_subject[subject,]) %>% 
  mutate(subject_estimate = b_treatment + r_subject) %>% 
  mutate(subject = reorder(subject, sort(subject_estimate))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = subject, x = subject_estimate)) +
  stat_slab()
```

Gives me this:
[image]

The line `mutate(subject = reorder(subject, sort(subject_estimate)))`  doesn't do anything, which might be fine as I probably need to reorder based on the mean of the posteriors, but when I try `mutate(subject_order = reorder(subject, sort(mean(subject_estimate))))` I get the error message:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `subject_order`.
> x arguments must have same length
> ℹ Input `subject_order` is `reorder(subject, sort(mean(subject_estimate)))`.
> ℹ The error occurred in group 1: subject = "X".

Any pointers welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two points for consideration:

1. Ungroup the result from `spread_draws`, otherwise you won't be able to reorder the levels of `subject`;
2. Use `fct_reorder` from the `forcats` package in tidyverse. It's designed for this exact purpose.

```
m %>%
  spread_draws(b_treatment, r_subject[subject,]) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(subject_estimate = b_treatment + r_subject) %>% 
  mutate(subject = fct_reorder(subject, subject_estimate, mean)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = subject, x = subject_estimate)) +
  stat_slab()
```

Result (data generated with `set.seed(123)`):

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you very much! In my code I had to add `mutate(subject = as.factor(subject))`  for `forcats:: fct_reorder` to work, but after that it was perfect.